# how do I make an Instantiate function with 4 parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make an Insatiate Function but it isn't really working it is suppose to make an platformer spawn but there is an error saying: Cannot Convert From '(int, int, int)' to 'Transform'

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab2, position, Quaternion.identity, (0, -Height, 0));
            position.x += spacing;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html
at the Declaration it says:

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

The fourth argument you have is `(0, -Height, 0)` which is `(int, int, int)`.
But it wants a Transform. (The Transform of the Parent it should have)

I dont know what you want with `(0, -Height, 0)`, maybe you could clear up?